# Probability of getting black or white

Tags: infinity

If I have a bag of black and white marbles, say 10 black and 10 white, I have a 50% chance of either getting black or white.  What if the bag were infinite?  Can one talk about probability when dealing with infinite sets?

I ask this question because I was reading a popular mathematics book and the author said that if one threw a dart at the number line, the odds of landing on a natural number were almost zero because the set of Uncountables was so much larger.

Comment: Short answer: you can but you use measure theory etc. Simple counting of possibilities no longer suffices.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you are trying to ask. What if the bag were infinite? What are you trying to ask?